# Data driven form with nested components in angular 2

Tags: forms, angular, tabs, nested-forms

I have a tabset with each tab containing a component which wraps up the content for that tab.
My tabset has the parent form and each nested component has form group of each own.

```
<form [formGroup]="parentForm">
  <tabset>
    <tab>
      <custom-component></component>
    </tab>
  </tabset>
</form>
```

My Custom Component wrap

```
<div formGroupName="tabOneDetail"></div>
```

This throws error as nested component is considered as part of parent component.

Comment: What is the error? I suspect you have to pass `formGroup` in your `custom-component`

Comment: inline template:0:5 caused by: formGroupName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.

Comment: Here is a good article for your case https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2

Comment: Getting below error
inline template:20:33 caused by: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

Comment: Thanx for the reference..it worked.
So now i have my main form containing tabs with nested components.